# Array_walk_recursive - Как сохранить дерево?

Tags: php, php7, php8

array_walk_recursive - рекурсивно перебирает массив вне зависимости от уровня вложенности.

Как при этом на выходе сохранить тоже дерево? Уровни вложенности подмассивов.

Comment: array_walk_recursive  никак не модифицирует исходный массив.. так что вопрос не имеет смысла.

Comment: Что значит не имеет смыла. Как вообще возможно перебрать многомерный массив и на выходе сохранить его дерево?

Comment: перечитай комментай **до первой точки**

Comment: Не модифицирует, но новый собрать ведь возможно?

Comment: Быть может есть аналогичная функция которая еще и модифицирует?

Comment: ааа. понял.... тебе надо пройтись и в каждом элементе что-то поменять? . я думал просто применить функцию (типа вывести значение элемента...к примеру)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно передать элемент по ссылке (внимание на знак аперсанда в аргументе функции!):

```
$sweet = array('a' => 'apple', 'b' => 'banana');
$fruits = array('sweet' => $sweet, 'sour' => 'lemon');

function test_print(&$item, $key)
{
    $item .= 666;
}

array_walk_recursive($fruits, 'test_print');
print_r($fruits);
// Выведет:

Array
(
    [sweet] => Array
        (
            [a] => apple666
            [b] => banana666
        )

    [sour] => lemon666
)
```

---

Если надо сохранить и предыдущий массив, то просто перед функцией надо скопировать массив в вдругую переменную и работать уже с ней

Comment: Работает, а с ключем возможно? Проделывая тоже самое, не выходит.

Comment: Нет, нельзя. Надо по-другому что-то делать. А зачем менять ключ?

Comment: Не менять его, пропустить значение через htmlspecialchars,addslashes

Comment: .......з-з-зачем?

Comment: Быть может строчку отправят с с различными кавычками, с кодом. Который в итоге исполнится на стороне сервера.

Comment: Кто отправит? Причём тут сервер? Это я, кстати, спрашивал в предыдущем твоём вопросе в виде комментария, ты так и не ответил... Ты пытаешься защищаться сам не понятно от чего.... а htmlspecialchars нужен для вывода на клиенте, но никак не на сервере